# trying to print using nth-child() in python script and selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver, chromium

Im Using selenium and python3.
I have a [LIST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbulZ.png) id like to loop through in my script using nth-child(1n)

```
for n in self.driver_web_browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Estadocombo > option:nth-child({n})'):
            str.append(n.text())
            print(str)
```

Im getting an error please help.

for n in self.driver_web_browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Estadocombo > option:nth-child({n})'):

File "/Users/ef/Desktop/MyBot/myBot/BOTS/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 614, in find_elements_by_css_selector
return self.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
File "/Users/ef/Desktop/MyBot/myBot/BOTS/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1007, in find_elements
'value': value})['value'] or []
File "/Users/ef/Desktop/MyBot/myBot/BOTS/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/Users/ef/Desktop/MyBot/myBot/BOTS/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
(Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.102)

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: you should be using find_elements which return the list of webelements

Comment: @Sureshmani , thanks that did help but still having an issue

Comment: @edward - Do you want to extract the text of the dropdown? Or you want to extract the text of the specific element from the dropdown?

Comment: @DilipMeghwal I am trying to extract the whole drop down list. Let me try the solution below. I had not used Select. However i found a different solution that also works .The Select method looks easier which is great! Much appreciated!

Comment: @Sureshmani Thanks for the answer. it also worked for me and its easier.

Answer (score 1):

Since these are select and option values, you can use the Select class

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


data = [] 
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Estadocombo'))
print(select.options)
for opt in select.options:
    data.append(opt.text)
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

> This also works for printing The whole list

```
basecss = '#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Estadocombo > option'
        events = self.driver_web_browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(basecss)


        for index, val in enumerate(events, 1):
            name = self.driver_web_browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("{}:nth-child({})".format( basecss,index))
            print(index,val.text)
```